# The design of BLE application with frequent connect/disconnect scenario , how should I optimize reocnnection?

Tags: optimization, embedded, bluetooth-lowenergy

I am working on BLE application on a embedded platform where there are frequent connect/disconnect events. The issue I am seeing is re-connection takes too long. The high frequency of connect/disconnect is a part of usage scenario so I can't change that. What I can do is make the re connection more efficient. I noticed, the bulk of re-connection is spent of service/characteristic discovery of other devices.

I still want to make sure the service/characteristic of the connecting device hasn't been changed. In stead of discovering all the service , can we instead use a characteristic that has the hash of all the service/characteristic on the device? So each device can compare the received hash with the stored one. Only in case of mismatch perform full service discovery. Is there a precedent of doing it in BLE?

Comment: Which platform do you use? In the latest Bluetooth version there is support for a hash of all services and characteristics exactly as you wish. But both ends must support that feature. The "old" way was using bonding + the service changed characteristic to speedup reconnections, while still supporting the case when services change.

Comment: It depends on OS you use. Let say on Windows it can be easy implemented by storing all characteristic data in your application. Once you get that data (Hand,e, UUID, others) you can simple read characteristic value using this data without need to read all services and characteristics. It also possible to execute connection to device only when you read value from it.

Comment: @Emil This is for embedded platform.  I am looking into Bluetooth 5.0 but I don't think it is that widely used yet. I have to make sure it is able to paired to both Android and IOS phones. I am not sure if IOS and Andriod have version 5.0 implemented yet.

Answer (score 0):

Bluetooth Low Energy (BLE) allows devices to leave their transmitters off most of the time to achieve its “Low Energy”.
I would expect a central device to subscribe to notifications from the peripheral. That way the peripheral only turns on and transmits when there are updates.

The other approach would be to put the data (or hash) in the advertising data (manufacturer data or service data) like many sensor beacons do. That way you might not need to connect at all or only connect if needed.